# Question 4.K of Bartle's Element of Integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I've have lots of trouble proving the next question of Bartle's book:

If $(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ is a finite measure space, and if $(f_{n})$ is a real-valued sequence in $M^{+}(X,\mathcal{X})$ which converges uniformly to a function $f,$ then $f$ belongs to $M^{+}(X,\mathcal{X}),$ and 
$$\int f d\mu=\lim\int f_{n} d\mu.$$

I don't understand correctly the proposition.

First: why does it ask the condition of a finite measure space?

Second: I guess that the hipotesis of uniform convergence is to create an increasing monotone sequence,to guarantee the pointwise convergence and then using Monotone Theorem Convergence, but I'm not sure of this.

Is there another way to prove this easily?

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is not finite you have the counterexample $f_n(x) = (1/n)\chi_{[0,n]}(x)$ for $X = \mathbb{R}^+$. Here $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ but $\int_X f_n \to 1 \neq \int_X f = 0$.

Note that

$$\left|\int_Xf_n \, d\mu  - \int_Xf_ \, d\mu\right| \leqslant \int_X |f_n-f| \, d\mu$$

and convergence follows easily if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ while $X$ has finite measure.

For every $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon/\mu(X)$ when $n \geqslant N$ for all $x \in X$, whence

$$\left|\int_Xf_n \, d\mu  - \int_Xf_ \, d\mu\right| < \int_X \frac{\epsilon}{\mu(X)} \, d\mu = \epsilon$$

Comment: Wow! Many thanks! You have a great domain of Measure Theory. Again a clever answer.

Answer (score 1):

@RRL's answer does not quite work in this context, as in this part of the book, the integral is only defined for non-negative measurable real-valued functions ($M^+$). Further, just to be picky, you cannot chose $\epsilon/\mu(X)$ as the measure could be null.

Given that, I think the following is more suitable:

Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $f_n \longrightarrow f$ uniformly, $\exists n_0\ \in\mathbb{N}\ \forall n\geq n_0\ f < f_n + \epsilon$, and because $f_n$ and $g(x) = \epsilon$ are in $M^+$, then $f_n + \epsilon \in M^+$, and $\forall n\geq n_0$
$$\int f d\mu \leq \int (f_n + \epsilon)d\mu = \int f_n d\mu + \int\epsilon d\mu = \int f_n d\mu + \epsilon\mu(X)$$
and because $\mu$ is a finite measure and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary, we have that $\forall n\geq n_0$ $$\int f d\mu \leq\int f_n d\mu$$

Similarly we show that, for some other $\epsilon$ and $n_0$, $\forall n\geq n_0$ $$\int f_n d\mu\leq\int f d\mu$$ and therefore the limits hold on both inequalities, yielding the desired identity.